# Need help with pen tool

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tools

Let's say I've completed a path and the pen tool is no longer selected.( It's a straight line, not a closed circle.)

Now I want to start from the ending point again and continue the line. How do I do this without starting a new Initial anchor point?  I don't want to begin a new path.

Thanks! (I'm running Photoshop elements CS3)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to select the `Pen Tool` and then *activate* the end point by clicking it. The cursor should look like this:

[image: Selecting an endpoint with the Pen Tool in Photoshop]

I'm using Photoshop CS5 though, so let me know if this doesn't work.